# UISearch Bar keyboard is not open in ios 8 device

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, xcode6, uisearchbar

UIsearchBar is not working properly , Keyboard is not open when click on search bar in ios 8 device

Comment: did you run code on simulator.if you run on simulator reset simulator and try again.

Comment: In simulator key board is not appear but search functionality working fine with system keyboard . But I am run in real device when i click the search bar keyboard is not appear and application is hang

Comment: did you try reset simulator?

Comment: Yes I try reset simulator , In ios 7 Device it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Search Bar is present in Model View Controller , I am Implementing Like this

```
searchObj = [[ICMOSearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ICMOSearchViewController" bundle:nil];
searchObj.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
searchObj.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:searchObj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

searchObj.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet; The key board is not appear and application is hanged .

Now I am changing to

```
searchObj.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
```

It's working fine